# I cannot find the way to move the text to the middle of the DIV

Tags: html, css

The following is the div in which my text is located, currently I cant make it come down from the top of the div.

```
<div class="caption">
    <h1>About me</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum In minim laboris dolor non incididunt nostrud amet dolor adipisicing consequat ut ex veniam cillum enim sint ut elit.</p>
</div>

.caption{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: center;
}
.caption h1,p{
}
```

Comment: your html please?

Comment: This is the div I'm talking about                                                                                                          <div class="caption">
  <h1>About me</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum In minim laboris dolor non incididunt nostrud amet dolor adipisicing consequat ut ex veniam cillum enim sint ut elit.</p>
 </div>

Comment: Hi Danilo, please take a look at these guidelines and update your question with more information so people can assist you.https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Mainly, you are missing the markup that these styles are targeting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you need a height specified on the div so that the text knows what space it is centering in.
2. flex is more reliable for this

   ```
   <div class="caption">
      <h1>About me</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum In minim laboris dolor non incididunt nostrud amet dolor adipisicing consequat ut ex veniam cillum enim sint ut elit.</p>
   </div>

   .caption{
     font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
     text-align: center;
     /* not very reliable -- vertical-align: center; */
     /* add flex for centering purposes */
     display:flex;
     flex-direction:column; /* not the default row */
     justify-content:center; /* vertically centered because flex direction is column */
      height:15em; /* so it knows what space is available to center in */
   }

   .caption h1,p{
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the text is vertically aligned, but your div is only as tall as the text that it contains.

I would try to add `border: 1px solid #000;` to your .caption to see how the div is spacing out.

-
As suspected your text is vertically aligned, but because a height, or padding is not being specified it's only the height of the text that it contains, and it's at the top of the page.

The best practice to solve this, is to set a height of the div and use a flexbox.

Check out some reading information here:
https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-vertically-center-text-with-css.html#table-display

And you can find an example with your code here:
https://codepen.io/danhebdon/pen/qQJwjY

Comment: I'm new here, should I just drop the whole html code ?

Comment: I think that's the best way if you don't have a lot. Alternatively you could use an online web dev display tool like https://codepen.io/

Comment: I added it there

Comment: As I suspected, I think that the height of the div is the issue. I'll edit my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

In order to vertically align your text, you'll need to give your container div some height. There are 2 examples in the snippet below. They both demo the size of your divs using a background color. The first shows that text is technically vertically centered because it is taking up the entire height. The second shows how you can use a display of flex as an easy solution to vertically align elements:

```css
.caption {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: teal;
}

.caption2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: coral;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="caption">
  <h1>About me</h1>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum In minim laboris dolor non incididunt nostrud amet dolor adipisicing consequat ut ex veniam cillum enim sint ut elit.</p>
</div>

<div class="caption2">
  <div>
    <h1>About me</h1>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum In minim laboris dolor non incididunt nostrud amet dolor adipisicing consequat ut ex veniam cillum enim sint ut elit.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I managed to move the text downwards but now the header and the paragraph are on the same line (sorry but I'm a beginner in html and css)

Comment: In the 2nd example, the one with the display of flex, I added a wrapping div around the h1 and the p tags. This is done so that the flex only operates on the wrapping div.